# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias en Laravel

Tags: laravel

> La consulta $data me tira un error    "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1066 Not unique  table/alias: 'organizador' (SQL:
>   select `unidades`.`unidad` from   `organizador`    inner join
>   `organizador` on `organizador`.`unidad` = `unidades`.`id`)*

```
public static function organizar_get(Request $request)
    {

        $actividades=actividades::all()->pluck('ao','id');
        $gerencia=gerencia::all()->pluck('ga','id');
        $unidad=unidades::all()->pluck('unidad','id');
        $año=años::all()->pluck('año','Id');

        $data =\DB::table('organizador')
            ->join('organizador', 'organizador.unidad', '=', 'unidades.id')
            ->select('unidades.unidad')
            ->get();



        return \View::make('organizar',compact('gerencia', 'unidad', 'actividades','año'))->with([
            'organizador' => $data,
            'contador' => 0
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: a la tabla organizador con cual estas tratando de hacerle el join?

Comment: organizador con unidades    lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar un select me tire todas las unidades el nombre que tienen

Comment: pues el detalle es qu el JOIN lo estas haciendo a la misma tabla, por eso el error

Comment: seria al reves entonces  o como podria hacerlo

Comment: ya lo resolvi gracias

Comment: No entiendo por qué no utilizar Eloquent, eso reduce estos errores de sintaxis.

Answer (score 2):

El `JOIN` lo debes de trabajar con las 2 tablas que deseas la vinculación, de este modo

```
$data =\DB::table('organizador')
            ->join('unidades', 'organizador.unidad', '=', 'unidades.id')
            ->select('unidades.unidad', 'organizador.columnaElegida')
            ->get();
```

Es decir con el facade `DB` eliges a la tabla principal, posterior en el método `JOIN` pasas el nombre de la tabla asociada indicando que la igualdad se encuentra por ejemplo con la llave primari y la llave foránea de cada una

al final en el `select()` indicas las columnas que deseas obtener

O bien mediante el uso de los modelos si es que así estas trabajando

```
$data = Organizador::join('unidades', 'organizador.unidad', '=', 'unidades.id')
                ->select('unidades.unidad', 'organizador.columnaElegida')
                ->get();
```